# Memory usage of canvas context in IE11/Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory, html5-canvas

I am facing a high memory usage issue in IE11/Edge, in a scenario where multiple offscreen canvases are used to render the contents of different images of size 1536*1536. I assume the the issue is because of the memory taken by the context object of the canvas. As the number of objects increases, the memory usage increases eventually causing slowness to the system.

Following is an isolated sample where this memory usage pattern can be seen.

```js
var context;
var src = 'data:image/png;base64,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'

function createContext() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    alert('context created');
  }
  //1536*1536
  img.src = src;
}

function clearContext() {
  context = null;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createContext()">Create context</button>
<button onclick="clearContext()">Clear context</button>
```

Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/xv9moj5h/

In the sample, I have a simple image of size 1536*1536 being drawn in a canvas(The actual images are different). While profiling I see that the memory taken by this object is 9MB in IE11/Edge whereas it is very less in Chrome/Firefox.

**IE 11**
[image: Screenshot in IE 11]

**Chrome**
[image: Screenshot in Chrome]

When the object is cleared, the memory is released. But in my actual use case, these context references need to be retained.

What could be the reason for the difference in the behavior between the browsers and is there any way the memory used by the context can be reduced in IE11/Edge.

Thanks in advance for any help